# Selenium IDE - waitFor "child element"

Tags: selenium, testing, ide

I'm trying to run a selenium test on a select tag. I'm currently running it as a "waitForText" but don't want my test to be subject to the pre-existing categories.

Is there a waitFor option that would allow me to get the child element of an id?

[Selenium Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzrSM.png)

Comment: "I'm trying to run a selenium test on a <I think you intended to finish this sentence>".

Comment: Your question is far too nebulous in its current state.  Please add more detail and relevant code.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information. Here is the drop down we're testing on: http://screencast.com/t/YlghmdfV

I want to be able to have the test run without taking into account the pre-existing options in the drop down. I'd like to be able to setup a waitFor that will work without having to provide a value for the command to work on the target. 

In other words, I want the test to execute as soon as the field is populated, regardless of what the values are (since the values for our drop downs will always be different). This will help us standardize our testing. Thanks for the help!